# What is wrong with this instance : ArrowApply Automaton?

Tags: haskell

I want Automaton to have instance ArrowApply, but Control.Arrow.Transformer.Automaton hasn't.
I think the following code will behave well :

```
data Automaton b c = Auto {runAuto :: b -> (c, Automaton b c) }

app :: Automaton (Automaton b c, b) c
app = Auto $ \(f,x) -> let
    (u, m) = runAuto f x
    nextApp m = Auto $ \(_,x) -> let
        (u', n) = runAuto m x
      in (u', nextApp n)
  in (u, nextApp m)
```

Probably, The existence of unused argument would be not good.
However I can't have any concrete idea of bad example, please tell me any of it.

Comment: The [laws for `ArrowApply`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:ArrowApply) relate it to `Arrow` and `Category`. It's not meaningful to consider if application is correct without an `Arrow` and `Category` instance. I assume you are using the `Arrow` and `Category` instances for `Automaton (->)` from [`Control.Arrow.Transformer.Automaton`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arrows-0.4.4.1/docs/Control-Arrow-Transformer-Automaton.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will not satisfy [ArrowApply laws](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:ArrowApply),

it actually fails with the first law:

```
first (arr (\x -> arr (\y -> (x,y)))) >>> app = id
  :: ArrowApply a => a (t, d) (t, d)
```

Let's first define a helper function:

```
iterateAuto :: [b] -> Auto b c -> [c]
iterateAuto [] _ = []
iterateAuto (x:xs) a = let (y, a') = runAuto a x
                     in y : iterateAuto xs a'
```

On the right hand side we get:

```
*Main> iterateAuto [(0,0), (1,0)] (id :: Auto (Int, Int) (Int, Int))
[(0,0),(1,0)]
```

But on the left hand side (here I had to name your implementation `app'`)

```
iterateAuto [(0,0), (1,0)] (first (arr (\x -> arr (\y -> (x,y)))) >>> app' :: Auto (Int, Int) (Int, Int))
[(0,0),(0,0)]
```

I'm quite sure that if `ArrowApply` for `Automaton` were possible, it would be in `arrows` package. It's hard to explain why there can't be one. I try to explain my intuition. The `ArrowApply` is equivalent to `Monad`, and `app` is kind of monadic `join`. The `Automaton` is kind of stateful computation, yet every `Automaton` carries it's own state, not the global state as in `State` monad. In pure setting the next state of the automaton is given to us on each iteration in the result pair. Yet if we would have `app`, the state of inner automaton is lost.

Another naive implementation of `app`:

```
app'' :: Auto (Auto b c, b) c
app'' = Automaton $ \(f,x) -> let
    (u, m) = runAuto f x
    nextApp = app''
  in (u, nextApp)
```

will fail on the second law

```
first (arr (g >>>)) >>> app = second g >>> app
```

Let's take a stateful `incr` as `g`

```
incr :: Auto Int Int
incr = incr' 0
  where incr' n = Automaton $ \x -> (x + n, incr' $ n + 1)
```

and helper method

```
helper :: Arrow a => (Int, Int) -> (a Int Int, Int)
helper (x, y) = (arr (+x), y)
```

Then we see that equation doesn't hold for a very simple input as well:

```
*Main> iterateAuto (map helper [(0,0),(0,0)]) $ first (arr (incr >>>)) >>> app''
[0,0]
*Main> iterateAuto (map helper [(0,0),(0,0)]) $ second incr >>> app''
[0,1]
```

I have [the runnable code as a gist](https://gist.github.com/phadej/5599ca222c1c66b10b12)

One wicked idea would be to make a version of Automaton by exploiting IORef or [STRef](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-STRef.html)

```
data STAutomaton s a b c = STAutomaton (STRef s (Automaton a b c))
```

but that is probably the awkward way of using `Kleisli (ST s)` or `Kleisli IO`.

Comment: Thanks! In fact, I want to make an `Arrow` which is same as that `STAutomaton`. Can it be made a correct instance of `ArrowApply`? Or is it wrong way of implementing 'local state'? (Now I'm thinking `ArrowCircuit` can represent variable, so I'm attempting it. What do you think about it?)

Comment: There are nice tricks presented in the recent ICFP paper. I didn't do the exercise, but you *should* be able to simulate local state using `ArrowChoice` and `delay` from `ArrowCircuit`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zgNRM8tZguY