# Can functional reactive programming (FRP) be expressed using monads?

Tags: javascript, haskell, functional-programming, reactive-programming, monads

I've been reading up on [Functional Reactive Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming), and though I have not used monads extensively in any language, I can't help but see them *everywhere* in the FRP design.

[This question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028250/what-is-functional-reactive-programming) have some fantastic descriptions of what functional reactive programming *is*, and I won't attempt to replicate that here. Basically, FRP creates relationships between values that change over time.

So can't this be represented monadically? Encapsulate the code that requires the values that are modified over time in a monad, call it `Signal`, then use those signals like so (using Haskell do-notation for simplicity).

```
do
  mx <- mouseX
  my <- mouseY
  wave <- currentTime >>= liftM sin
  -- do some stuff with these values
```

Or is there more to FRP than I'm understanding? Are there paradigms that prevent using such a simple representation using monads? Or is this a valid (if perhaps simplified) understanding of how FRP works?

Comment: Arrow is more abstract concept related to FRP you should look it first and you see than monadic approach is less preferable https://www.haskell.org/arrows/ https://wiki.haskell.org/Arrows-based_Functional_Reactive_Programming  also "Arrows, Robots, and Functional Reactive Programming" http://haskell.cs.yale.edu/?post_type=publication&p=175

Comment: @Sigrlami I admit I haven't yet taken the time to understand arrows, but thanks for the links. I'll look into those.

Comment: in javascript, wouldn't a very simplistic definition of frp be that you treat all your data as streams? There is definitely a stream monad so isnt frp just programming with a specific (very powerful) monad?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Behaviors* could be given monad operations. After all `Behavior a` is semantically `Time -> a`, which is [`Reader Time`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.1.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html).

Also *Events* which are semantically `[(Time, a)]` could be given at least `Applicative` instance which would resemble `ZipList` structure.

Yet, even these are theoretically possible and elegant, in practice they are hard to implement. You could check ["Controlling Time and Space: understanding the many formulations of FRP" by Evan Czaplicki](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Agu6jipKfYw) for more information.

For example [`sodium`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sodium-0.11.0.3) have [*kind of* monadic bind for `Behaviors`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sodium-0.11.0.3/docs/FRP-Sodium.html#v:switch):

```
switch :: Behavior (Behavior a) -> Reactive (Behavior a)
```

but instead of working in the pure category, we work in Kleisli category of `Reactive` monad. Thus we can do a bit more.

One exercise which highlights the difficulties, is to try to implement [`ArrowApply`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:ArrowApply) for [`Automaton`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arrows-0.4.4.1/docs/Control-Arrow-Transformer-Automaton.html). [SO provided spoiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603108/what-is-wrong-with-this-instance-arrowapply-automaton/27610945#27610945)

Comment: That talk was especially helpful for someone like me who doesn't have a fantastic grip on the intricacies of Haskell's higher-order abstractions. Thanks for the explanation!